# Material UI's pallet not applied to Button component?

Tags: material-ui

I've set up my theme's pallet (the colours arnt actually all #0000):

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#0000',
      light: '#0000',
      dark: '#0000',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#0000',
      light: '#0000',
      dark: '#0000',
    },
    info: {
      main: '#0000',
      light: '#0000',
      dark: '#0000',
    },
    success: {
      main: '#0000',
      light: '#0000',
      dark: '#0000',
    },
    error: {
      main: '#0000',
      light: '#0000',
      dark: '#0000',
    },
  },
});
```

When I use the button component with the color prop it's not using these styles:

```
<Button variant="contained">Default</Button>
<Button variant="contained" color="primary">
  Primary
</Button>
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
  Secondary
</Button>
<Button variant="contained" disabled>
  Disabled
</Button>
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  href="#contained-buttons"
>
  Link
</Button>
```

Why does it not use the colour values from my pallet? Sure I could override the CSS in the button component, but that's the point of the pallet system if I have to do this?

Comment: Have you wrapped your whole application with MuiThemeProvider and passed the theme as prop?

Comment: I'd forgotten to use this provider component in Storybook!

Comment: So, Is it working now?

Comment: @SirajAlam yes.